# strtok function thread safety

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety, strtok

I have been spending some time in debugging a programme which gives segmentation fault. The bug is quite indeterministic and intermittent, which is annoying. I narrowed it down to the calling of `strtok()`. I suspect that it is the calling of `strtok()` to split string in two different threads that causes the segmentation fault. Can I call `strtok()` in two different threads?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not tag a question C++ when it is actually a C question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`strtok()` is not reentrant so it should not be used from threaded applications, use `strtok_r()` instead.

Comment: I tried using Dev-C++ to make a C program, and strtok_r wasn't available :( I'm not sure what standard/version/compiler devcpp uses

Comment: The POSIX standard version of strtok has an extra pointer. where it can keep the state. So that version is thread-safe as long as different treads using different pointers.

Answer (score 8):

`strtok()` is not MT-safe because it stores some intermediate variables globally and reuse them at each call (see you don't have to pass again the string each time you call `strtok()`).
You can have a look at the man pages of methods you are using and it is always indicated at the end if it is MT-safe or not.

When a method is not MT-safe (multi-thread safe or reentrant), you should look for same method with suffix _r meaning reentrand. In your example, `strtok_r()` as suggested in the other answer.