# Read in Separate Numbers from a line in C

Tags: c, file-io

I need to read in separate numbers from a file and then use them in code.

For example the file will say things like

```
2 5
8 9
22 4
1 12
```

And right now I have:

```
while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL)  
{
    ListRef test = newList();
    token = strtok(line, " \n");
    int x = token[0] - '0';
    int y = token[2] - '0';
}
```

Which works fine, except not if one or both of the numbers is multiple digits. How would I change this to read in both numbers (there will always be two, and that's it) on a line, regardless of their length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL)  
{
    int x, y;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d", &x, &y) != 2)
        ...report format error...
    ...use x and y as appropriate...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a line of numbers in `line` (as in your `while` loop), you can do it like this:

```
char *p;
p = strtok(line, " \n");
while (p != NULL) {
    sscanf(p, "%d", &num);
    /* do something with your num */
    p = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
```

But note that `strtok` may have thread safety issue. See [strtok function thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031075/strtok-function-thread-safety)

If you just want to read all the numbers, regardless of the lines, just use `fscanf`:

```
while (fscanf(in, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    /* do something with your num */
}
```