# thread free pointer

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads, free, valgrind

I'm trying to work with threads in C and i'm having some problems with freeing a pointer
if this is the thread function

```
void *executor_func(void *param) {
char *lineEx = (char *) malloc (1024);

size_t lenEx = 1024;
ssize_t readEx;

FILE * fpEx;
char* pchEx;

fpEx = fopen(file, "r");

if (fpEx == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: couldnt open file\n");
    exit(0);
}

while ((readEx = getline(&lineEx, &lenEx, fpEx)) != -1) {
    pchEx = strtok(lineEx, " ");

        //DO MY STUFF WITH THE LINE I RECEIVE FROM FILE
    }
free(lineEx);
fclose(fpEx);

return NULL;

 }
```

Imagine that i execute multiple threads of executor_func()... 
the free(lineEX) is giving me problems at Valgrind... why is that ?

Comment: What is the specific error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the documentation : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

> The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens.  On
>   the
>          first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in str.
>          In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str should be
>          NULL.

As the strtok manual says : 
Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:

```
   * These functions modify their first argument.

   * These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

   * The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.

   * The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not
     thread safe.  Use strtok_r() if this matters to you.
```

If you get illegal frees maybe it is related to this ([from Valgrid manuals](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html)):You will also get this message if you try to free a pointer that doesn't point to the start of a heap block.Memcheck keeps track of the blocks allocated by your program with malloc/new, so it can know exactly whether or not the argument to free/delete is legitimate or not. Here, this test program has freed the same block twice. As with the illegal read/write errors, Memcheck attempts to make sense of the address freed. If, as here, the address is one which has previously been freed, you wil be told that -- making duplicate frees of the same block easy to spot.

And lastly have a look at this : [strtok function thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031075/strtok-function-thread-safety)
You can try to use strtok_r()

Comment: But it's only giving me error message of invalid free because i'm running multiple threads of that same executor_func()... may be one of the those threads is deleting the lineEx from the other ? is that possible ?
How can i fix it ?

Comment: How can i use strtok_r when i want to do this: 

char *pchE = strtok(NULL, " ");

???