# How to use strtok in string?

Tags: c++

Edit: Sorry, it should be c++. how to use `strtok` in string?

```
FQ_ID_line[0]="1,26665;TUK.006.8955.FQ;TUK;400 BB 2 FQ;400 BB 2;899;FQ;Z_SCCFG1;Z_BSCFG1;333";
FQ_ID_line[1]="2,26223;TUK.002.8955.FQ;TUK;400 BB 2 FQ;400 BB 2;;FQ;Z_SCCFG1;Z_BSCFG1;333";
for(int FQ_i=0;FQ_i<FQ_Number;FQ_i++)
    {
        printf( "FQ_ID_line[FQ_i]=%u\n", FQ_ID_line[FQ_i] );
        char * FQ_array=strdup(FQ_ID_line[FQ_i].c_str());
        char *chars_array=strtok(FQ_array,seps);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        strcpy(DataLine[FQ_i].analog_comp_id,chars_array);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        strcpy(DataLine[FQ_i].RTU_abbr,chars_array);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        strcpy(DataLine[FQ_i].analog_scc_fep_group,chars_array);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        strcpy(DataLine[FQ_i].analog_bsc_fep_group,chars_array);
        chars_array=strtok(NULL,seps);
        strcpy(DataLine[FQ_i].RTU_number,chars_array);
        DataLine[FQ_i].float_RTU_number=atof(chars_array);
        free(FQ_array);
    }
```

the ouput is :

> DataLine[0].analog_comp_id=TUK.006.8955.FQ
>
> DataLine[0].RTU_abbr=TUK
>
> DataLine[0].analog_scc_fep_group=Z_SCCFG1
>
> DataLine[0].analog_bsc_fep_group=Z_BSCFG1
>
> DataLine[0].float_RTU_number=333
>
> DataLine[1].analog_comp_id=TUK.002.8955.FQ
>
> DataLine[1].RTU_abbr=TUK
>
> DataLine[1].analog_scc_fep_group=Z_BSCFG1
>
> DataLine[1].analog_bsc_fep_group=333
>
> DataLine[1].float_RTU_number=

**I want to the ouput:**

> DataLine[0].analog_comp_id=TUK.006.8955.FQ
>
> DataLine[0].RTU_abbr=TUK
>
> DataLine[0].analog_scc_fep_group=Z_SCCFG1
>
> DataLine[0].analog_bsc_fep_group=Z_BSCFG1
>
> DataLine[0].float_RTU_number=333
>
> DataLine[1].analog_comp_id=TUK.002.8955.FQ
>
> DataLine[1].RTU_abbr=TUK
>
> DataLine[1].analog_scc_fep_group=Z_SCCFG1
>
> DataLine[1].analog_bsc_fep_group=Z_BSCFG1
>
> DataLine[1].float_RTU_number=333

Comment: The code looks mostly like C but you've tagged the question as C++ - which is it? Do you want a C solution (with C library functions like `strtok`, `strcpy`, etc) or a proper C++ solution ?

Comment: [`std::strtok` is not thread safe and should therefore be avoided.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4031101/1007504)

Comment: It's C++... there's a "cout" near the top.. As usual someone goes into C++ for one of its least useful features rather than all its strong ones.

Comment: It may be C++ because of the cout, but in its spirit, it looks like  C, with all those strcpy(), strtok(), free(), printf(), etc...

Comment: The two adjacent semicolons are swallowed by one `strtok(NULL,seps)`. You'd be better off using `string`'s functions to parse the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cause of the problem:**

The function strtok() has many problems, due to the fact that subsequent calls depend on previous calls, and this dependency is managed in an unsafe manner:

- it's not thread safe (see Robert's comment, and C++ standard section 21.8 pt 14)
- if one function you call would use strtok() without you knowing, your next call to strtok() would return a lot of surprises.

Now your problem comes from the input string part:  `...400 BB 2;;FQ;...`, and the definition of [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) :   *In subsequent calls, the function (...) uses the position **right after the end of last token** as the new starting location for scanning. To determine the beginning and the end of a token, the function first scans from the starting location **for the first character not contained in delimiters** (which becomes the beginning of the token)*

So everything works well until it returns "400 BB 2". The next ";" will according to this algorithm be skipped and your code will jump over the empty field (;;) as if it didn't exist.  Not ony do you have a shift in the following fields, but your last call to strtok() may even cause segmentation fault.

**Solution:**

Best avoid strtok(). If you like c-style, you may consider instead the use of  strpbrk() with some adaptation in your code.  For example:

```
char* get_field(char*p, char*& next, const char* s) // by ref as it's c++
{
    if ((next = strpbrk(p, s)) != NULL)
        *next++ = '\0';
    return p; 
}
```

with the following usage to replace strtok():

```
char* next;
char *chars_array = get_field(FQ_array, next, seps);
... 
chars_array = get_field(next, next, seps); // instead of strtok(NULL, seps)
...
```

My personal recommendation, with C++, would be to **consider [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) expressions** provided in the standard (or in boost), which would also allow for consistency check on you input data.

The full code would then look like:

```
regex fmt("([0-9]*,[0-9]*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*);([0-9]*\.*[0-9]*)");

for (int FQ_i = 0; ...)
{
    smatch sm;
    printf("FQ_ID_line[FQ_i]=%u\n", FQ_ID_line[FQ_i]);  // ok, a cout would be better
    if (regex_match(FQ_ID_line[FQ_i], sm, fmt)) {
        DataLine[FQ_i].analog_comp_id = sm[2];
        DataLine[FQ_i].RTU_abbr = sm[3]; 
        DataLine[FQ_i].analog_scc_fep_group = sm[8];
        DataLine[FQ_i].analog_bsc_fep_group = sm[9]; 
        DataLine[FQ_i].RTU_number = sm[10]; 
        DataLine[FQ_i].float_RTU_number = stof(sm[10]); 
    }
    else
        cout << " ** Non matching line ignored !!\n";
}
```

By fine tuning the regex, you could then check even more for consistency before assigning (Here I just did the minimum for the sake of the example).