# C programming login system

Tags: c

I'm trying to make simple login system, based on `txt`.
The `file` looks like

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

But my code check just last line of `txt`, not each line.

```
int write_login_and_pass() {
    char login[30], pass[30];
    int select3;

    printf("\n|---------Login:");
    scanf("%s", login);
    printf("|---------Password:");
    scanf("%s", pass);

    sign_In(login, pass);
    _getch();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
int sign_In(char login[30], char pass[30]) {
    FILE *file;
    char user2[30], pass2[30], fc;
    file = fopen("Customers.txt", "r");
    char arra[128][128];

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[128];
        do {
            fscanf(file, "%29s %29s", user2, pass2);
        }while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL); 
                if ((strcmp(login, user2) == 0) && (strcmp(pass, pass2) == 0)) {
                    printf("\n>>>User and password correct!<<<\n");
                    fc = main_menu();
                }
                else {
                    printf("\n>>>User or password incorrect!<<<\n");
                    system("PAUSE");
                    fc = sign_In(login, pass);
                }
    }
    else printf("File was not founded");
    fclose(file);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of every called function (like [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), whose return value should be checked). Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb`.

Comment: Take a closer look at your loop reading the file. And if you can't see it directly then please take some time to [read about how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn how to use a debugger to step through code line by line.

Comment: Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic.

Comment: i think you should put the if else statement inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
do
{
        fscanf(file, "%29s %29s", user2, pass2); // 1)
}
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL); // 2)
```

First, you read in a pair of user password 1), then you *try* to read the end of the line 2) - but on success, as in a while loop, you re-enter before having evaluated the passwords read so far...

Two options now, first, the simple one:

```
char user2[30], pass2[30], fc;
file = fopen("Customers.txt", "r");
if (file)
{
    while(fscanf(file, "%29s %29s", user2, pass2) == 2)
    {
        // do comparisons here
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Be aware that you *absolutely* rely on correct file format, i. e. always following one user followed by his/her associated password – whitespace does not matter, by the way, so the file could even look like this:

```
u1 p1
u2
p2 u3
p3 u4 p4
```

However, one single time one of the pairs missing, your login is *entirely* broken!

Second option: reading line by line:

```
char user2[30], pass2[30], line[128];
file = fopen("Customers.txt", "r");
if (file)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)
    {
        if(sscanf(line, "%29s %29s", user2, pass2) == 2)
        // ^  (!)
        {
            // do comparisons here
        }
        // else: line is invalid!
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

I personally would prefer [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) instead of sscanf, though, as you do not have to copy the strings this way:

```
char *user2, *pass2, line[128];
file = fopen("Customers.txt", "r");
if (file)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)
    {
        if((user2 = strtok(line, " \t") && (pass2 = strtok(NULL, " \t"))
        {
            // do comparisons here
        }
        // else: line is invalid!
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

(only drawback: strtok is not [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031101/1312382))